# Instagram hashtag search permissions

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

I downloaded a jQuery plugin a while back that worked really well in displaying posts from a particular hashtag from instagram. Since the recent updates to instagram, the hashtag search returns an error

“This client has not been approved to access this resource.”

I have been told that I need to get permission to now access a specific hashtag, but since this is not an app and I am not the developer, how do I go about doing that specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have access to Instagram account otherwise you cannot do anything.
By the way, you have that jQuery plugin? Maybe I can take a look at it and help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

To get this level of information you will need a developer account with Instagram and then get the appropriate token for accessing this information through the API. The scope will need to set correctly during the oauth2 generation of the token, it will probably need the "public_content" scope.